# Issue with Setting Nested Object for Query in Nestjs Swagger

Tags: nestjs, swagger

I'm working on a NestJS application where I have a controller method that accepts a complex query object for fetching categories. The query object includes filters and pagination, and I'm using Swagger to document the API. However, I'm facing issues with setting up the nested object structure for the query parameters in Swagger.

DTO Definition:

```
export class GetAllQueryDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({
    type: FilterDto,
    required: false,
    isArray: true,
    description: 'Array of filters for query'
  })
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  filters?: FilterDto[];

  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({
    type: PaginationDto,
    required: false,
    example: PaginationDto,
    description: 'Pagination for query'
  })
  @ValidateNested()
  pagination?: PaginationDto;
}


export class FilterDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({
    type: RangeDto,
    description: 'Range value for filter'
  })
  range?: RangeDto;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsEnum(QueryOperators)
  @ApiProperty({
    example: QueryOperators.GreaterThan,
    description: 'Query operator'
  })
  operator?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({
    example: 'value',
    description: 'Value to filter'
  })
  filterValue?: string | number | boolean | Array<string> | Array<number>;

  @ApiProperty({
    example: 'fieldName',
    description: 'Field name to apply filter'
  })
  fieldName: string;
}

export class PaginationDto {
  @IsNumber()
  @Min(1)
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({
    example: 10,
    description: 'Number of items per page'
  })
  limit?: number;

  @IsNumber()
  @Min(1)
  @IsOptional()
  @ApiProperty({
    example: 1,
    description: 'Page number'
  })
  page?: number;
}

export class RangeDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    example: '2023-06-17T18:00:00Z',
    description: 'Start range of filter '
  })
  start: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    example: '2023-06-17T18:00:00Z',
    description: 'End range of filter'
  })
  end: string;
}
```

Controller Method:

```
@Get('')
async getAllCategories(@Query() query: GetAllQueryDto): Promise<CommonResponseDto<CategoryResponseDto[]>> {
  // Method implementation
}
```

Expected Swagger Output:

[image]

```
Name: filters
Type: Array
Location: (query)
Description: Array of filters for query

Name: pagination
Type: Object
Location: (query)
Description: Pagination for query
```

Actual Swagger Output:

[image]

```
Name: range
Type: *
Location: (query)
Description: Range value for filter

Name: operator
Type: string
Location: (query)
Description: Query operator
Example: >

Name: filterValue
Type: *
Location: (query)
Description: Value to filter
Example: value

... (other parameters)
```

I've tried different configurations in the DTO and controller, but Swagger is not generating the expected nested object structure for the query parameters. How can I configure my DTO and controller method to achieve the desired Swagger output?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add `@ApiProperty()` to each property of the `FilterDto` as well. add it to all the inner class properties. it will work.

eg =>

```
  @ApiProperty()
  startGeoCoordinate: Coordinate;
```

Coordinate class

```
export class Coordinate {
 @ApiProperty()
 latitude: number;
 @ApiProperty()
 longitude: number; 
}
```

Comment: I do have `@ApiProperty()` for all nested level classes, I have updated the question dto please check.